# resolv.conf after reboot on CentOS 5.5 EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, dhcp, resolv.conf, dhclient

I'm having trouble getting my CentOS 5.5 EC2 instances (both i386 and x86_64) to properly populate resolv.conf after booting. No matter what I do, I end up with the default EC2 resolv.conf:

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search compute-1.internal
nameserver 172.16.0.23
```

What I really want to do is set my own search domain and prepend two nameservers. First, I tried adding */etc/dhclient.conf*:

```
prepend domain-name "mydomain.ec2 "
prepend domain-name-server 1.2.3.4
prepend domain-name-server 1.2.3.5
```

That didn't work. So I also tried placing the *dhclient.conf* file in */etc/dhcp/* and */etc/dhcp3*. Neither worked. So I also tried creating */etc/dhclient-enter-hooks* and overriding the _make_resolv_conf()_ method to prevent dhclient-script from overwriting resolv.conf:

```
make_resolv_conf() {
 ;
}
```

That had no impact either.

The only solution I have come up with is to add an extra init script that rewrites resolv.conf. That works, but I'd really like to do this the "right" way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try PEERDNS=no?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
PEERDNS=no
```

To your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 (or equivalent)

If that doesn't work, you could use the chattr hack:

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: i get i to work, if i set onbootup=yes :)

Answer (score 2):

Given the age of this question, I assume you found an answer; but for those who find this question looking for help: If this is inside a VPC, you need to go into the VPC console and access dhcp-options-sets (https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home#s=dhcp-options-sets) and create a new dhcp options set. Make a note of the amazon id of the new options set (dopt-XXXXXXXX)

Next, go to "Your VPCs" (https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home#s=vpcs), click "Change DHCP Options Set" near the top, then choose the amazon ID of your new options set.

This might help:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html

Comment: I never did get it to work and just kept using my custom init script approach. Unfortunately, it wasn't in a VPC. Now that most of our instances are in VPCs, we're using the technique you outlined. Just a strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should address your issue http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-to-avoid-resolv-conf-been-modified-by-dhcp-client-422431/

Comment: Nope. As I mentioned, I tried using dhclient.conf and that didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add following DNS entries in NIC related network scripts (e.g., `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` for `eth0`)

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8 
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a real simple fix.
Set /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts to this:
 PEERDNS="no"
 DNS1=8.8.8.8
 DNS2=8.8.4.4

This will stop the EC2 dns from inserting into the resolv.conf.